# List of surviving Uchiha

Tags: naruto

I originally thought that the only surviving members after the Uchiha massacre were Sasuke and Itachi, but more and more seem to be revealed.  Is there a canonical list of surviving members of the Uchiha clan after the massacre?

Comment: Now it's only sasuke. But soon there will be sarada..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The following:

- **Uchiha Itachi** - Who performed the massacre. Was killed later by Sasuke (according to his plan), then reanimated, eventually to die again (permanently, this time).
- **Uchiha Sasuke** - Who was spared by Itachi in hopes of making him strong. Still alive.

That's about it from the traditional ones.

- **Madara Uchiha** - Who was dead during the massacre, was also later reanimated.
- Uchiha Obito also survived the massacre, in fact, he helped Itachi execute it (as Tobi).

#### And also

> [Sarada Uchiha](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sarada_Uchiha), Sasuke's and Sakura's daughter, also counts for the purposes of this list.

Comment: Must... not... hover... spoiler.

Comment: @Alenanno: Don't, seriously, if you aren't up-to-date with the manga, don't.

Comment: I won't. :D Even if I have a (kind of defined) feeling of what it says.

Comment: OK, phew.  So all this uchiha survivor stuff I'm seeing on google is just fanfic.  I thought I missed something.

Comment: try hovering in the wrong places and you will understand :P

Comment: itachi! is no more ! (with waterfall of tears) :(

Comment: @Sai: True, but the question is regarding who survived the massacre. Itachi did in fact survive the massacre.

Comment: oh yah yah! my bad.. I jumped to answer directly :D

Answer (score 3):

Itachi Uchiha
Sasuke Uchiha

Spoiler:

> Madara Uchiha - he was alive during the obito flashback but not sure if he was still alive after the clan massacre.
>  Obito Uchiha - Tobi turned out to really be Obito.

Comment: You're having unexposed spoilers!

Comment: downvote reason?

Comment: I downvoted because you didn't have a spoiler mark on one of the characters you referred. If the first one had, the second one should have it to. Actually, we should assume that an answer should be readable by someone who has just seen few episodes/read few chapters, and not be spoiled. (After editing, I removed my downvote...)

Comment: i understand...

Comment: Also, sadly, I wasn't alive during the Uchiha Massacre. Tobi was already masked when he helped Itachi with his job, so it's very likely I already passed away.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: most of the Uchihas mentioned below are alive currently. In the Naruto series, only Sasuke, Itachi, and Obito were still alive. In the Boruto, Sasuke and Shin, another introduced Uchiha. The other ones are Uchihas that were introduced (as alive, duh) in the Naruto and Boruto series.

Yes, all of the above answers are correct:

1. Sasuke Uchiha
2. Itachi Uchiha (dies in the fight against Sasuke)

and (**SPOILER**):

> 3. Madara Uchiha (saved Obito who was under the tree in the 3rd Shinobi World War, probably died soon afterwards)
>  4. Obito Uchiha (unintentionally fakes his death, dies in 4th Shinobi World War)

But there are still a few more that weren't introduced properly:

5. Shisui Uchiha (Danzo took one of his eyes, Shisui entrusted his other eye to Itachi, then suicided)
6. Fugaku Uchiha (Sasuke and Itachi's father)
7. Mikoto Uchiha (Sasuke and Itachi's mother)
8. Indra Otsusuki (not really an Uchiha, but the ancestor of all Uchihas)
9. Izuna Uchiha (Madara's brother, Madara took both of Izuna's eyes out)
10. Shin Uchiha (unknown until Boruto, experimented on by Orochimaru)
11. Other people like Baru, Naka, Naori, Rai, etc. Uchiha (important characters in the Uchiha Clan's war history).

Look, there are many Uchihas but most are irrelevant or not important to how the history of Naruto and others were affected.