# Who is this running kid wearing a shirt with Uchiha symbol?

Tags: naruto

There's a kid wearing a shirt with Uchiha symbol, but I have no idea who s/he is.

[image: Uchiha still has "this" person]

Who is this kid?

Comment: What episode is this from?

Comment: If we look at just what was shown to us in the show, the only Uchiha members killed were those in the Uchiha village that night. Although it hasn't been revealed, it is likely that not every Uchiha member was present in the clan village that night.

Answer (score 11):

After doing some digging around, I discovered this scene is from the episode [The Night of the Tragedy](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/The_Night_of_the_Tragedy). According to the wiki, this is simply just an animation error

> **Trivia**
>
> In one scene, there is an animation error that an Academy student is shown having an Uchiha crest on the back of his shirt, despite that scene happening after the incident.

We know for a fact that [there are very few Uchiha remaining](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/12/list-of-surviving-uchiha). While it is plausible, as @Hostile Amigo mentioned, that not every Uchiha was present during the incident, this episode is part of the *Kakashi: Shadow of the ANBU Black Ops* filler arc and shouldn't be counted towards canon.

Comment: This is a great answer, but I wonder if the Wiki itself is sourced on that animation error piece...

Comment: @Makoto I updated my answer, expanding on it a little bit