# Who's the other Uchiha Danzo mentions while recruiting Torune into the foundation

Tags: naruto

Danzo notices young Shino when strolling along with Shino's father and demands that a member of the Aburame clan be donated to the foundation, and he also mentions that an Uchiha member has been confirmed to join the foundation.

Refer to Ep. 317 "Shino vs. Torune!", is he/she in any way be this one mentioned on [Who is this other Uchiha member?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/41445/who-is-this-other-uchiha-member)? The reasoning is because when Shino is young, Naruto and Sasuke are young too... so I'm sure that Sasuke's the only Uchiha alive at that point and the foundation always wished to kill all the Uchiha.

Or is it simply that the timeline is just before Uchiha massacre? and the Uchiha member being mentioned is just an ordinary member not worth mentioning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Canon

No clue.  The episode [Shino vs. Torune!](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Shino_vs._Torune!) is a filler episode during the 4th Great Ninja War. As such, there is no canonical information who the Uchiha member is.

## Non-Canon; Speculation Only

It's possible the Uchiha member Danzō mention was actually Itachi. In the episode, Danzo says to Shino's father

> As you know, The Foundation is where ANBU agents are developed

While The Foundation lead by Danzō, it is a subdivision of [ANBU](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Anbu)

> In Konoha, there exists a special branch of the Anbu known as [Root](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Root). It was created and led by Danzō Shimura

[Itachi](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Itachi_Uchiha) joined the ANBU at age eleven, and Torune looked roughly the same age when joining The Foundation. Despite Itachi being apart of ANBU, and not The Foundation, Danzō still had influence over ANBU memebers and [their missions](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Uchiha_Clan_Downfall).

> Itachi reported the mission's success to the Third Hokage. The Third, having been unaware of Itachi's assignment from Danzō, regretted to hear the news